# Does dividend tax witholding mean that ETFs aren't necessarily great for personal pensions overseas?

Tags: etf, retirement, international, pension, withholding-tax

### Question

For tax-shielded personal pensions (US IRAs, UK SIPPs), should one prefer to "manually replicate" ETFs by holding stocks directly instead of buying ETFs, to avoid [US withholding tax on the dividends from stocks inside an ETF](https://www.bankeronwheels.com/how-to-reduce-etf-withholding-tax/)?

### Context

I'm a US citizen living in the UK. Brokers [don't sell](https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Taxation_as_a_US_person_living_abroad#EU_and_UK_residents_and_PRIIPs) US-domiciled ETFs to people living outside of the US. I therefore hold Ireland-domiciled ETFs like [SWDA](https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/251882/ishares-msci-world-ucits-etf-acc-fund?switchLocale=y&siteEntryPassthrough=true) in my Traditional IRA.

SWDA replicates the MSCI World Index. I'm starting to wonder if it might be worth it just to replicate SWDA by manually buying its top N holdings. Holding the stocks directly in this way would ensure that their dividends are properly shielded within my IRA.

### Theory

The question is about a choice: I could own SWDA's top N holdings directly, or use the same amount of money to buy SWDA, which itself contains M holdings, where M >> N. There must be some minimum value N_min such that if N >= N_min, the marginal diversification benefit of choosing SWDA is outweighed by the 15% tax drag on the underlying stocks' dividends.

I guess this question amounts to asking for an extremely rough estimate of N_min. If N_min <= 30 then it might be worth replicating SWDA by buying its top N_min holdings. If N_min is closer to 300, then I might not bother.